# How I can remove the cursor from below query? +

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-performance, query-performance

```
DECLARE @U_CHK   TABLE (
            ACCOUNT_ID NUMERIC
           ,START_NO NUMERIC
           ,END_NO NUMERIC
           ,SEQ_NO NUMERIC
           ,USED INT
        )

DECLARE @ST_NO NUMERIC
       ,@END_NO  NUMERIC
       ,@ACID    NUMERIC
       ,@SEQ_NO  NUMERIC  

DECLARE cCurChk           Scroll CURSOR  
FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT AC_ID
          ,ST_DOC_NO      
          ,ST_DOC_NO      
          ,END_DOC_NO     
    FROM   AC_LVL_INVEN
     GROUP BY
           ST_DOC_NO
          ,END_DOC_NO     
          ,AC_ID          

OPEN cCurChk
FETCH NEXT FROM  cCurChk INTO @ACID,@ST_NO,@SEQ_NO,@END_NO                            
WHILE @@Fetch_Status=0
BEGIN
    WHILE (@SEQ_NO<=@END_NO)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @U_CHK
        VALUES
          (
            @ACID
           ,@ST_NO
           ,@END_NO
           ,@SEQ_NO
           ,0
          )  
        SET @SEQ_NO = @SEQ_NO+1
END FETCH NEXT FROM cCurChk
INTO @ACID,@ST_NO,@SEQ_NO,@END_NO
END   CLOSE cCurChk  DEALLOCATE cCurChk  

UpDate @U_CHK  
SET USED = 1 FROM @U_CHK Ch INNER JOIN FA_Trans FA(NOLOCK) ON Fa.
    Account_ID = Ch.Account_ID AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10) ,Ch.Seq_No) = Fa.Instrument_No
    WHERE FA.Status>4 AND STATUS<>12 AND Ac_Head_Type<>1 AND Trans_type = 'Debit'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a merge statement to do the insert / update in place of the cursor.  Here is an example

```
MERGE dbo.FactBuyingHabits AS Target
USING (SELECT CustomerID, ProductID, PurchaseDate FROM dbo.Purchases) AS Source
ON (Target.ProductID = Source.ProductID AND Target.CustomerID = Source.CustomerID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET Target.LastPurchaseDate = Source.PurchaseDate
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (CustomerID, ProductID, LastPurchaseDate)
    VALUES (Source.CustomerID, Source.ProductID, Source.PurchaseDate)
```

Take a look at [Technet - Inserting, Updating, and Deleting Data by Using MERGE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx)